# grails joda datetime millis not saved in DB?

Tags: grails, jodatime

I try to search for the current money of a product based on the validFrom & validUntil properties which holds the information when a prices expires.

When a price changes, I set the validUntil property of the old price from null (which means valid to infinity) to the Datetime until it is valid. Then I create a new price where the validUntil is 1!! millisecond after the old was valid until. This way I have all the time a valid price for each product.

this is my testcase

```
def endDateOld = DateTime.parse('2015-09-14T10:49:00+02:00')
log.debug "a "+endDateOld.millis
def startDateNew = new DateTime(endDateOld).plusMillis(1)
log.debug "b "+startDateNew.millis
```

produces

```
a 1442220540000
b 1442220540001
```

when I save it to DB

```
def money = new MoneyProduct(validFrom:endDateOld, validUntil:startDateNew, amount:199)
money.save(flush:true)
```

and I get the the values I get:

```
log.debug "from "+money.validFrom.millis+" until "+money.validUntil?.millis
```

output:

```
from 1442220540000 until 1442220540000
```

MoneyProduct class:

```
class MoneyProduct {

    BigDecimal amount 
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("EUR")
    DateTime dateCreated

    DateTime validFrom
    DateTime validUntil

    static constraints = {
        validUntil(nullable:true)   
        amount(nullable:false)
    }

    static belongsTo = [product:Product]
}
```

Maybe is a configuration problem?
Config.groovy:

```
// Added by the Joda-Time plugin:
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateMidnight, class: org.joda.time.DateMidnight
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime, class: org.joda.time.DateTime
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeZoneAsString, class: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDurationAsString, class: org.joda.time.Duration
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentInstantAsMillisLong, class: org.joda.time.Instant
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentInterval, class: org.joda.time.Interval
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate, class: org.joda.time.LocalDate
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime, class: org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime, class: org.joda.time.LocalTime
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentPeriodAsString, class: org.joda.time.Period
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentTimeOfDay, class: org.joda.time.TimeOfDay
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentYearMonthDay, class: org.joda.time.YearMonthDay
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentYears, class: org.joda.time.Years
}
```

**EDIT:**

It looks like the joda datetime data type is stored as a DATETIME in mySQL which has only second precision. How can I change this?

Ok. I need to overrride the default hibernate mapping. I tried:

```
static mapping = {
    validFrom sqlType: "DATETIME", length: 3
    validUntil sqlType: "DATETIME", precision: 3
}
```

By default, it seems, grails is createing a datetime column (I use the joda plugin) without length/precision which defaults to 0. This means no precision = seconds. In my case I need millisecond precision which is the length/precision of 3 (6 would be nano) as @Adam Michalik suggested

When I change the length to 3 manually grails updates and retrieves the milliseconds perfectly.

Comment: What is your DB? What is the DB column type?

Comment: just edited. DB is mySQL and column is automatically maped to DATETIME

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell mysql what size of second fractional you want - of the range 0 to 6. Use

```
DATETIME(6)
```

for maximum available precision. By default it's 0, so you don't get any milliseconds at all.

To quote [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html):

> To define a column that includes a fractional seconds part, use the syntax `type_name(fsp)`, where type_name is `TIME`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`, and `fsp` is the fractional seconds precision. For example:
>
> `CREATE TABLE t1 (t TIME(3), dt DATETIME(6));`
>
> The `fsp` value, if given, must be in the range 0 to 6. A value of 0 signifies that there is no fractional part. If omitted, the default precision is 0. (This differs from the standard SQL default of 6, for compatibility with previous MySQL versions.)

Comment: okay. But grails is creating the tables for me. How do I tell grails to create the column with the precision I want?

Comment: I'm no Grails expert, but this seems how you override the default generated table settings: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.0/ref/Database%20Mapping/type.html See the `mapping/type` block to override the SQL type

Comment: I could force grails like you described and I would do this when it was another type. But as it is the joda plugin and the plugin is doing their own mapping I think this in not the sollution. There should be an way to tell joda / or usertype to use another mapping